# DataTable Merge Different Data

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I'm trying to wrap my head around DataTable.Merge because it seems to be what I want to do, which is merge the differences from one DT into another DT.

Here's two identical DataTables, with a primary key, followed by a merge operation.  Event provided to spy on them.

```
  //first table
  var dt1 = new DataTable();
  dt1.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt1.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
  dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt1.Columns["Col1"] };

  //second table.. identical to first
  var dt2 = new DataTable();
  dt2.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt2.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
  dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns["Col1"] };

  //some data
  object[] o1 = { "1", "A" };
  object[] o2 = { "2", DBNull.Value };
  object[] o3 = { "3", "C" };
  object[] o3New = { "3", "C New" };

  //add data to first table
  dt1.Rows.Add(o1);
  dt1.Rows.Add(o2);
  dt1.Rows.Add(o3);

  //add data to second table - third row is different
  dt2.Rows.Add(o1);
  dt2.Rows.Add(o2);
  dt2.Rows.Add(o3New);

  //register an event on row change
  dt1.RowChanged += Row_Changed;

  //merge second table into first
  dt1.Merge(dt2);

  //check for changes to first table
  var dt3 = dt1.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
  if (dt3 == null)
    Console.WriteLine("No changes to dt1");
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("Modified rows in dt1:" + dt3.Rows.Count);
  }

  //check for changes to second table for the heck of it
  var dt4 = dt2.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
  if (dt4 == null)
    Console.WriteLine("No changes to dt2");
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("Modified rows in dt2:" + dt4.Rows.Count);
  }
```

To go with the above, this event to catch changes:

```
private static void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine("Row changed {0}\t{1}\t{2}", e.Action, e.Row.ItemArray[0], e.Row.ItemArray[1]);
}
```

The output shows **all three rows** being changed by way of the event handler, but at the end it says nothing at all has changed when calling GetChanges.  If I had my way, in this setup only one row would change.  But simultaneously all three are "changing" - but none are changed.

I'm apparently doing something wrong.  Can someone smarter than me explain why?

Alternately, is there some other way to merge only different data fields in an identical schema primary key DataTable setup?